# Conditional Formatting clear with specialcells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not getting any errors with my code. In fact, nothing is happening at all. I'm trying to go through a workbook, and clear all cells with matching conditional formatting. Here's my rudimentary code. Tried Ctrl+H method also and that didn't find any matching cells..

```
Sub clear_cells()

Dim range1, range2 As Range
On Error Resume Next

Set range1 = Range("a1:l500")

With range1
Set range2 = range1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameFormatConditions)
range2.ClearContents

End With

End Sub
```

Cell A1 has the format that I want to match. The other cells in range1 have a mixture of Type, Value, format etc.

Comment: I think this will only check the first cell in your range, ie A1.

Comment: Also, I am not sure this is restricted only to conditional formatting?

Comment: So ignore my comment. Have you tried using 'Clear'?

Comment: @QHarr - don't quote me but I think it is only CF.

Comment: xlCellTypeSameFormatConditions - this will select all 
cells in the specified range that contain the same format 
as the *first* cell specified in range. If the first cell 
specified in the range does not have conditional 
formatting - you will get a run time error '1004'. So first cell in range must be the one to match against. https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/21342-xlcelltypesameformatconditions.html    Basically backs up your comment @SJR  but also looks like above seems ok ?

Comment: It is rather esoteric so we can be forgiven for being unsure I think.

Comment: OP does say he wants to match with A1 (which I missed first time). @QHarr

Comment: Anyway if nothing is happening that suggests there are no matching cells. Comment out the On Error line and see what happens.

Comment: Also, declare Range1 as Range not as variant which it implicitly is.